# Function Self Reference

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, functions are simply objects that can be invoked. So what is the easiest way for the body of a function to reference the actual function object?

`this` can be used to reference the containing object that a function (or more specifically, a method) is called from. But I believe `this` never refers to the actual function object itself.

Obviously, `bind`, `call`, or `apply` could be used to change the value of `this` for the function. Or `bind` could be used to create a version of the function that is always given a reference to itself as its first parameter.

But is there any simpler way? I suspect not, but I could be wrong.

Comment: The [name of the function](http://jsfiddle.net/rfcrore8/) would be the simplest.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I cannot think of a case where a named function-expression cannot substitute for an anonymous function-expression. So I would suggest naming the function if you are going to call it from within itself (i.e., if you are going to use recursion):

```
function myFunc(someArg) {
    ...
    ...
    myFunc(someNewArg);
}
```

This works even if it is a reference:

```
var myFunc = function(someArg) {
    ...
}
```

You can even use a recursive IIFE (immediately-invoked function expression) if you don't want to pollute the namespace:

```
(function myFunc(arg) {
    ...
    myFunc(someOtherArg);
})(0); //some initial value
```

Furthermore, doing something like this:

```
someOtherFunction(function myFunc(arg) {
    ...
    myFunc(otherArg);
});
```

Also works and won't pollute the namespace.

Comment: why it not work in that case : '{ a: function someFunc(){ someFunc.foo ='bar'  } }'

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a frustration of mine, because you used to be able to use arguments.callee which would get you a reference to the function.  As someone else mentioned, this is no longer possible.

There is a pattern emerging for this... and that is to name the function yourself as well as assign it.  It looks like this:

```
my_obj.myfunc = function foo(arg1, arg2) {
     // do stuff
     foo.call(this, new_arg1, new_arg2);
}
```

This way you can reference the named function and go about your business.  Note that you do have to use the `.call` syntax if you want to call it as a method (so that `this` has meaning) but apart from that, it's pretty straightforward.

Another option is to do a truly functional approach, where you pass the object to be operated on to a function:

```
function foo(obj, arg1, arg2) {
    // do stuff
    // call recursively:
    foo(obj, new_arg1, new_arg2);
}

// assign as method:
my_obj.foo = function(arg1, arg2) { 
     foo(this, arg1, arg2);
}
```

It could be argued that this is better and more flexible.  I think it's a matter of taste, really.

Comment: arguments.callee was removed mainly due to optimization problems. I understand why they removed it, but it somewhat bugs me that you can get a hold of a reference to just about anything in JS... except the currently running function. There are other ways to accomplish what you need now, but it just seems wrong that you can not get access to the running function if it is anonymous.  It also bugs me that with this deprecation you also lose the ability to get at the caller. But I could rant all day about this.  It is the way it is.  The above covers most cases where you'd need it.

Answer (score 2):

`arguments.callee` inside of a function will be a reference to the function itself, but it's not exactly good form. You should name the function, then you can just use the name inside of the function

Comment: `arguments.callee` is [forbidden](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) in ES5 strict mode; I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Cool, I forgot about arguments.callee. But yeah, if it is deprecated/forbidden, it's not what I'm looking for. :/

Answer (score 2):

I would give your functions a name, then use that to reference them.  If you have a declared function or a function variable, then it already has a name.

```
function test1(){
    // test1();
}

var test2 = function(){
    // test2();
};
```

If you have an anonymous function, you can actually give it a name.  That name will *only* exist inside the function.

```
someFunc(function test3(){
    // test3();
});
// test3 will be undefined here
```

Answer (score -1):

You can, but since the function is anonymous, a dummy way to identify it shall be adopted.
You can learn a lot on how to do it by simply looking at this beautiful article:
[Anonymous Recursion in JavaScript](https://dev.to/simov/anonymous-recursion-in-javascript)

Comment: It seems like you are just plugging a link to your own article. This is a 4 year old question with an accepted answer already. You should also include code samples in your answer and cite the article as a source.

Comment: Hi. The article is not mine.
I just found it online while searching for the same question elsewhere, and I even commented it (but not created).

I can copy-paste what's inside that linked page if you prefer.

Comment: @the.reversengineer yes, it's definitely better to quote (relevant parts of) the article in SO answer - the solution in a nutshell. and then link the article for further information. there are multiple reasons for this. main reason is that any external resource can disappear - either site goes down, or gets restructured and the link leads nowhere.